# Помогите решить задачу, цикл for с вложенными циклами

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Нужно вывести таблицу умножения, на вход идут 4 числа, Программа должна вывести фрагмент таблицы умножения для всех чисел отрезка [a; b] на все числа отрезка [c;d]. Почти решил сам, но у меня не получается вывести все в одной таблице, в зависимости от количества переменных c,d, увеличивается количество таблиц. Вот мой код:

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
d=int(input())
a<=b
c<=d
for i in range(c,d+1):
  print('\t',*range(c,d+1),sep='\t')
  for j in range(a,b+1):
      print(j,j*i)




Пример на выходе:
7
10
5
6
    5   6
7 35
8 40
9 45
10 50
    5   6
7 42
8 48
9 54
10 60
Должно быть:
  5 6
7 35 42
8 40 48
9 45 54
10 50 60
Третий день мучаюсь!
```

Comment: Для чего нужны a<=b и следующая за ней? Про "третий день мучаюсь" вряд ли кто поверит, конечно.

Comment: Если учесть, что я только 2 недели как начал изучать Пайтон и программирование в целом, имея возможность учить его 2-3 часа в день, т.к. нахожусь в местах не столь отдаленных, то да 3 дня не мог решить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот откорректированный код:

```
a=int(input('Input a: '))
b=int(input('Input b: '))
c=int(input('Input c: '))
d=int(input('Input d: '))
if( (a<=b) and (c<=d) ):
    print('', *range(c,d+1),sep='\t')
    for i in range(a, b+1):
        print('\n', i, end='\t')
        for k in range(d-c+1):
            print(i*(c+k), end='\t')
```

Comment: И вам огромное спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

Где-то я уже это видел

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
for g in range(c, d+1):
    print('\t'+str(g), end='')
print(end='\n')
for i in range(a, b+1):
    print(str(i)+'\t', end='')
    for j in range(c, d+1):
        print(str(i*j), end='\t')
    print(end='\n')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АнтонПирожков не за что, примите ответ если вам подходит (галочка)